# changing the top of a div element based on the height of previous div element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am designing a simple webpage. In the webpages body there are two divs.

```
<body>              
    <div id="headerDiv">
        <img id="headerImg" src="./assets/dummy.png" width="15%" height="15%" alt="DummyLogo" style="float: left;"/>
        <h1>Flex Series Cloud Solutions</h1>                            
    </div>          
    <!--</div>-->                   
    <div id="nav">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {              
                $("#nav").load("./nav.php", function() {}); 
            });
        </script>
    </div>              
</body>
```

```css
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {  
    height: 100%;       
    overflow: hidden;
}
#headerDiv {            
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;  
    width: 100%;    
    padding: 1%;
    height: auto;   
    background-color: #f1f1f1;          
}
#nav {          
    position: absolute;     
    top: 18%;
    bottom: 0;      
    width: 15%;
    <!--height:84vh;-->
    height: 84%;
    padding: 1%;    
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

When I resize the webpage I want to adjust the `top` parameter of div nav corresponding to height of `headerDiv`. Please guide me on how to do that. I tried using following jQuery inside the `<head>`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var nav_div = $("#nav");
    var header_div = $("#headerDiv");
    nav_div.css("top", header_div.outerHeight);
});
```

It is not working. I randomly allotted percentage values to the top parameter of the nav which also didn't work out. The guidance can be programmatical or mathematical.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
        var nav_div= $("#nav");
        var header_div = $("#headerDiv");
        nav_div.css("top", header_div.outerHeight()+"px");
});
```

Comment: can u provide a fiddle?

Comment: check now it was jquery function

Answer (score 0):

Just stumpled on your question and I had similar problems a few months ago. try to use offsetHeight instead of outerHeight and add "px" if the solution from Piyush.kapoor doesn't work:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var nav_div = $("#nav");
    var header_div = $("#headerDiv");
    nav_div.css("top", header_div.offsetHeight + "px");
});
```